# Use my Microsoft account to connect to an Azure SQL Database (with Azure Active Directory)

Tags: python, sql-server, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to connect to a SQL Server. I'm trying to establish a connection between them using my Microsoft account. I need this connection to execute with Python. How can I do that? With the code I currently have I am getting a connection failed.

Here is my code:

```
# Add libraries needed for connecting to Azure SQL Database
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import exc
import urllib
import time


#~ Connection Parameters for SQL Server
server   = 'Server_name.database.windows.net'
database = 'database_name'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'   
# driver   = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
driver   = 'SQL Server' # Try this one if top doesn't work
# print (pyodbc.drivers()) # Used to see what drivers you have


#~ Setup connection strings for API
connection_string_1 = f"""Driver={driver};Server=tcp:{server},1433;Database={database}; Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"""
connection_string_2 = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string_1)
connection_string_3 = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?autocommit=true&odbc_connect={}'.format(connection_string_2)


#~ Try to connect to the DB. Print error and close if unsuccessful.
try:
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string_3, echo=False) #Echo will display all queries ran in the command prompt. Useful for debugging.
    DB_connection = engine.connect()
except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
    print('LDAP Connection failed: check password.')
    print('Program aborting and closing in 5 seconds.')
    time.sleep(5)
    quit()


print('File Complete - Connection')
```

Comment: Aside... don't use the `SQL Server` driver in new applications. This is the legacy "SQL Server Native Client" driver which was the old, deprecated and Windows-only driver that hasn't had any feature updates since SQL Server 2012 days and, finally, Microsoft has stopped distributing it. New applications should be using `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` or `ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server`, whichever is installed on your system.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77419136/edit) your question to include the full and complete text of the error message you're getting. (The posted exception handling code seems to be hiding the actual problem.) Based on what you've described so far... have you opened a hole in Azure Firewall to allow your VS Code computer to connect with the SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code for connection.

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy

server = "your_server_name.database.windows.net"
database = "your_database_name"
username = "your_username"
password = "your_password"
driver = "{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"
connection_string = f"Driver={driver};Server={server};Database={database};Uid={username};Pwd={password};Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword"
try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print("Connected to SQL Server")

    # Now, you can use 'cursor' to execute SQL queries.
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print(f"Connection failed: {e}")
```

Note: You need to install `pyodbc` and `sqlalchemy` packages.

```
pip install pyodbc sqlalchemy
```

Comment: I am getting this error message: 

Connection failed: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'my_email@xxx-xxx.com'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'my_email@xxx_xxx.com'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")

Comment: Check whether your username and password are correct. Whether the string format is correct.